# Java: Reading stream from URL with same domain as hosting

Tags: java, url, playframework, localhost, inputstream

In a Java app, should it be possible open a stream on a URL which has the same domain as the server running the app?

For example, I am running a Play! Framework app on:

```
http://www.my-domain.com/
```

And the `URL` I am trying to open an InputStream on is:

```
http://www.my-domain.com/public/zipfile.zip
```

When I try to access the `inputstream` via the URL `openStream()` method, the the app hangs (but still runs) and does not proceed any further (as if it has become locked).

The line of code causing the problem is as follows:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
```

**Extra Information**

The code works as expected when accessing a URL from a different domain, eg:

```
http://www.different-domain.com/public/zipfile.zip
```

I have tried using `127.0.0.1`, I have tried my network IP address and I have faked a real domain using `hosts`. None of these have worked, which leads me to believe this is a problem with a url being referenced from the same domain as the same as the app which is running it.

Comment: what do you mean by "my code seems to get stuck when opening a stream" Does it not responding ?

Comment: @SajanChandran Yes, it literally just hangs at that point and does not proceed past it.

Comment: Is your proxy is set properly ? have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: Does it work using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Damokles no unfortunately not - I'm about to add some more information to my question in regards to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you call 'self referencing' but if you mean that 'server' and 'client' are within the same application perhaps it's threading issue (like the same thread is trying to read and write to the stream at the same time)? I would take a thread dump 'jps' then 'jstack' from command line while your application is running and see what thread is blocking on.

Comment: +1 thanks, that does sound like a possible cause - I will give the thread dump a try. To clarify (although your interpretation sounds correct), by "self referencing" I mean that the server is `http://www.domain.com` and the url is `http://www.domain.com/public/zipfile.zip`

Comment: Ok, when trying to print a `jps` dump I get a nested exception: `java.net.socketexception network is unreachable`. The "jstack" dump is available but I am not sure what I am looking for in there. There are lots of "TIMED_WAITING" and a couple of "WAITING" threads but they are mainly "RUNNABLE". As far as I can see, none of them reference the same piece of memory.

Comment: not sure - when did you get exception? when running 'jps' or in 'jstack' output or in your app? :)

Comment: in jstack output there should be one thread with your code at url.openStream() - take a look what it's blocking on (if anything)

Comment: If I have the app running and call the "jps" dump, then the exception is thrown. Within the "jstack" it says "locked<>" with a reference to a location within memory, but it does not provide any information about what that is.